# Prove logical equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

\begin{gather}
(p \to q) \equiv (\lnot p \lor q) \\
\lnot(p \land q) \equiv (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)
\end{gather}

Can these be proven without truth tables?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  It will help us to answer it if you give the context, such as what other tools you're familiar with, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: If you want the better comment to what you know about this problem, then you need to at least try it.  This site is not for people to ask someone to do the problems for you.  The purpose of this site is to learn mathematics from professionals and users.

Comment: I proved this with truth tables. I want to know if there is other way. For example ".b" is one of the Morgan's laws, and obviously i cant prove Morgan law applying Morgan Law itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both statements are logical identities in propositional logic, typically taken as "axioms": In fact, we define the material conditional $p \rightarrow q$ to be equivalent to $\lnot p \lor q$: the implication is true whenever $p$ is false or whenever $q$ is true. The second is one of the equivalencies resulting from DeMorgan's Laws.

The best way to prove the given equivalencies is to show that they are equivalent for each possible assignment of truth values to $p$ and $q$ (and in the first case, they are identiclal merely by definition of the material conditional.)  This is precisely what a what a *truth-table* does: a "proof-by-cases" so to speak: in each of the above, there are four cases to consider: each row of the truth-tables represent one possible case; together, the rows exhibit only and all such cases. Once we prove that these identities are true in this manner, we are done, and we can accept them, and use them validly when proving more complicated equivalencies.

Note: depending on one's "formal system", the equivalencies taken as "axioms" i.e., as "most basic", may vary:

See [Propositional Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) for a more thorough explanation. But to start,:

> In general terms, a propositional calculus is a formal system that consists of a set of syntactic expressions (well-formed formulæ or wffs), a distinguished subset of these expressions (axioms), plus a set of formal rules that define a specific binary relation, intended to be interpreted as logical equivalence, on the space of expressions.

Comment: Ok, so when working with identities you cant probe them with another method?

Comment: Generally speaking, not when the identities are definitions, or fundamental "building blocks," as these are. And as are $T \lor p \equiv T$, $F \land p \equiv F$, $T \land p \equiv p$ and $F \lor p \equiv p$.

Answer (score 3):

amWhy provided an answer for axiomatic systems where the equivalences are taken as definitional.  However, in natural deduction systems, which typically don't have axioms *per se*, or have fewer, these equivalences, if understood as biconditionals, can be proven.  For sake of example, here's the first one:

1. - Assume $p \to q$.
2. - - Assume $\lnot(\lnot p \lor q)$.
3. - - - Assume $p$.
4. - - - $q$ by *modus ponens* with 1 and 2.
5. - - - $\lnot p \lor q$ by disjunction introduction with 4.
6. - - - $\bot$ by *falsum* introduction with 2 and 5.
7. - - $\lnot p$ by negation introduction with 3–6.
8. - - $\lnot p \lor q$ by disjunction introduction with 7.
9. - - $\bot$ by *falsum* introduction with 2 and 8.
10. - $\lnot p \lor q$ by negation elimination 2–9.
11. - Assume $\lnot p \lor q$.
12. - - Assume $p$.
13. - - - Assume $\lnot p$.
14. - - - $\bot$ by *falsum* introduction with 12 and 13.
15. - - - $q$ by *falsum* elimination with 14.
16. - - - Assume $q$.
17. - - - $q$ by reiteration with 16.
18. - - $q$ by disjunction elimination with 11, 13–15, and 16–17.
19. - $p \to q$ by conditional introduction with 12–18.
20. $(p \to q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor q)$ by biconditional introduction with 1–10 and 11–19.

The second has a similar structure (prove each of $\lnot(p \land q)$ and $\lnot p \lor \lnot q$ from the other, and then use biconditional introduction with the respective subproofs).

So, while using truth tables might be a very direct way to check whether two propositional formulae are equivalent, truth tables are not the *only* option.